# Finding the basis of the image and kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the map $f:\mathbb{R}_3[X]\to\mathbb{R}_3[X]$, such that $P\mapsto P+(1-X)P'$, I'm trying to find a basis of the kernel and the image of the map.

I think I was able to find a basis for the Kernel, namely $\mathcal{B}=\{1-X\}$, because indeed any polynomial of the form $k(X-1)$ is mapped to $0$ by $f$ because $\Big(k(X-1)\Big)'=k$, so $f\Big(k(X-1)\Big)=k(X-1)+(1-X)k=0$. 
So really my question is how do I find a basis of the image of $f$ ?

Since the basis of $Ker\,f$ has only one element (so the kernel has dimension $1$), and $dim(\mathbb{R}_3[X])=4$ I'm pretty sure the image of $f$ should have dimension $3$, that is the rank of $f$ should be $3$, but that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{1,X,X^2,X^3\}$ spans $\Bbb R_3[X]$, $\{f(1),f(X),f(X^2),f(X^3)\}$ spans $f\bigl(\Bbb R_3[X]\bigr)$. But $f(1)=f(X)$. So $\{f(X),f(X^2),f(X^3)\}$ spans $f\bigl(\Bbb R_3[X]\bigr)$ and so, since $\dim f\bigl(\Bbb R_3[X]\bigr)=3$, it is a basis of $f\bigl(\Bbb R_3[X]\bigr)$.